# Paginate in Rails 3 issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I'm currently working on a Reddit clone app that I had written in Rails 2 and I'm trying to bring it up to speed with new features in Rails 3. The app is very simple, it has a Links scaffold which has `:url`, `:description`, `:points`, and `:created_at`. The app routes to `links#submissions` where you can view all submitted links and submit a new link as well.

I've run into a problem with the `paginate` method in Rails 2 when displaying the links on the submissions page. I am currently running Rails 3.2.3 and I understand that I need to use the gem `will_paginate` in Rails 3 (which I have included in my `Gemfile`) but whenever I try to pull up `localhost:3000` I get this error message:

```
NoMethodError in LinksController#submissions...
undefined method paginate for #<LinksController:0x00000102ff5f98>
```

specifically on line 90 of the Links controller.

Here is what I have in my **LinksController.rb** (lines 90-93).

```
@link_pages, @Links = paginate :links, :order => order, :per_page => 20
@header_text = case ordering
    when 'hot' then 'Top rated submissions'
when 'new' then 'Latest submissions'
```

Is this not the correct way to use paginate in Rails 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `will_paginate`, you should use something like this in your controller:

```
@links = Link.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
```

In your view, the links for the given page will be stored in the `@links` instance variable.  You can iterate over that collection and display the links.

To show the links to other pages (of links), you use this somewhere in the view:

```
will_paginate @links
```

You can find more help for `will_paginate` here: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

However, for Rails 3, I prefer `kaminari` instead of `will_paginate`.  It uses Rails 3 scopes.

It looks like this in the controller:

```
@links = Link.page(params[:page]).per(20)
```

And this in the view:

```
paginate @links
```

You can read more about `kaminari` here: https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari

Also you can watch Ryan's Railscast on `kaminari` here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari

Comment: dude awesome thanks for pointing out `kaminari` ... way easy and i like the config abilities

Answer (score 1):

You need to call paginate on the model, so

```
Link.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20
```

or

```
Link.[arel query].paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20
```

should work.

To order by created descending example, you'd do something like:

```
Link.order("created_at DESC").paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20
```

Comment: weird i tried `Link.paginate` but what got this error `ArgumentError in LinksController#submissions , wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`

Comment: Sorry, you still need to pass in your arguments: Link.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20