# PG like query not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

So I've built a search into my blog app. My development environment is running mysql2 on my localhost. The following code works perfect in the dev enviorment:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

def index
 if params[:s]== ""
   #do nothing
 elsif params[:s]== "all posts"
   @posts = Post.page(params[:page]).per_page(7).order("id DESC").all
 else
   @posts = Post.page(params[:page]).per_page(7).order("id DESC").find(:all, :conditions=> ["title like ?", "%"+params[:s] + "%"])
 end
end
```

But when I push to Heroku which use PG it no longer works. Is there something I need to change in `@posts = Post.page(params[:page]).per_page(7).order("id DESC").find(:all, :conditions=> ["title like ?", "%"+params[:s] + "%"])` that  will make it work in pg?

Thanks!

Comment: How is it failing? Does it give an error, or is it matching too little or too much? What is being passed as the parameter, what do you expect that to match and what is actually matching?

Comment: PG needs simple quotes for the LIKE condition, its pretty picky!

Comment: @qqx its not returning any results

Comment: @MrYoshiji: *every* (standard compliant) database needs single quotes for character literals.

Comment: @MrYoshiji: Oracle, PostgreSQL, Firebird, DB2, Teradata, MySQL (in ANSI mode), SQL Server, Ingres, Vertica, Cubrid, HSQL, Derby, H2 - just to name a few.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first mistake is that you're using different databases in your development and production environments. This is a really bad idea, especially when one of those databases is as sloppy as MySQL and the other is as strict as PostgreSQL. Don't do this to yourself, set up PostgreSQL in your development environment if you're going to deploy on top of PostgreSQL and make sure you're using the same PostgreSQL versions in both environments.

Your second mistake is related to your first: [MySQL's `LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) is usually case insensitive:

> The following two statements illustrate that string comparisons are not case sensitive unless one of the operands is a binary string:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT 'abc' LIKE 'ABC';
>         -> 1
> mysql> SELECT 'abc' LIKE BINARY 'ABC';
>         -> 0
> ```

but PostgreSQL's is case sensitive and provides [`ILIKE` for case insensitive matching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE):

> The key word `ILIKE` can be used instead of `LIKE` to make the match case-insensitive according to the active locale.

So you want to use

```
Page.where('title ilike ?', "%#{params[:s]}%")...
```

with PostgreSQL. And if you want something will work more or less the same in both, you can probably get away with downcasing everything by hand:

```
Page.where('lower(title) like lower(?)', "%#{params[:s]}%")...
```

You might want to look into a full-text search system though, LIKE queries are often just an easy way to create table scans and no one likes table scans.

Comment: This is also giving me the error `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

Comment: `.where('title ilike ?', "%#{params[:s]}%")`

Comment: @Deekor: Are you calling that as `Page.where(...).page...`?

Comment: `@posts = Post.per_page(7).page(params[:page]).order("id DESC").where('title ilike ?', "%#{params[:s]}%")`

Comment: I cannot overstate how important the first sentence of this answer is. Using a different database for dev and for production is a huge mistake.

Comment: @Deekor: The clue is "1 for 0", the `where` call has 2 arguments. Perhaps your error is somewhere else.

Comment: And that line has four method calls on it. What is the whole error message?

Comment: stack trace says: `app/controllers/search_controller.rb:12:in `index'` and line 12 is that line i posted above

Comment: I got it. You were right it was the pagination. Apparently i was writing it wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957658/paginate-in-rails-3-issues
Thanks fo your help!